# Using a variable to access object member value

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to access *member values* of the following class:

```
public class EditorialDateFormat
{
       public string en; <------ TRYING TO GET ITS VALUE
       public string fr; <------ OR THIS VALUE
       public string Default;<-- OR THIS ONE
 }
public class Params
{
      public string Template;
      public string MainTagID;
      public string[] NavigationFilters;
      public EditorialDateFormat EditorialDateFormat;
}
public class Site
{
      public string Name;
      public string CreationFolder;
      public Params Params;
      public string[] Feed;
      public string Endpoint;
      public string[] TargetDatabases;
}
```

I could do it easily like : 
`site.Params.EditorialDateFormat.en`(for example) but "en" string is actually saved in a variable.

I tried the following code :

```
// Myvariable contains "en"
object c = GetPropValue(site.Params.EditorialDateFormat, MyVariable); 

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetMember(propName);
}
```

But it returns me a `MemberInfo` object without the member *value*
I would appreciate some help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: You´re almost there: you have to get the value for the obtained `MemberInfo` on the given instance of your class, something like : `GetMember(propName).GetValue(src, null)`.

Comment: Not sure but you want en value if null then fr and if that's also null then you want default value right?

Comment: Uttam Ughareja : yes that's my expected behaviour !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read *field* (public instance field's value), that's why we put `GetField`:

```
//TODO: rename the method: it doesn't read property (Prop) 
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName) {
  return src
    .GetType()
    .GetField(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EditorialDateFormat
{
    private string _en;

    public string en
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_en) ? _en : fr; }
        set { _en = value; }
    }
    private string _fr;

    public string fr
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fr) ? fr : Default; }
        set { _en = value; }
    }

    public string Default { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use it like `var c=site.Params.EditorialDateFormat.en`
in elegant way

Comment: Thank you for your help!